# How to handle exceptions?

Tags: c#, silverlight

It's a question about best .net practise.  I always caught and stored information about exceptions in all of my web and window forms applications as follows:

1. Surrounded each method with try catch(Exception exception)
2. For any layer except front layer, threw exception to the layer above
3. In the front layer, logged the exception to a log file (usually using log4config.dll) and presented a user friendly message to the user.

Is this the best way to handle exceptions? Or should I do something different in my next projects?

Comment: What do you mean by 1.Surrounded each method with try catch(Exception exception)

Comment: try{//do something} catch (Exception exception) {//do something}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following code is problematic because it overwrites the original stack trace for `e`, which makes problems harder to diagnose:

```
public void Foo() {
    try {
        Bar();
    } catch(Exception e) {
        throw e; // re-throw; overwrites original stacktrace in 'e'
    }
}
```

The following code does not have the above stacktrace overwrite problem, but is still unnecessarily verbose:

```
public void Foo() {
    try {
        Bar();
    } catch(Exception e) {
        throw; // re-throw; preserves original stacktrace in 'e'
    }
}
```

Both would be better written as below.  This is because, **if the only thing you are doing in your catch block is re-throwing the exception, there is no need to write the catch block at all:**

```
public void Foo() {
    Bar();
}
```

Comment: To be exact, "throw e" is worse because it loses the stack and recreates one, it should be just "throw" w/o any argument.

Comment: Thus proving how easy it is for well-intentioned code to make things worse :)

Comment: +1 for "if the only thing you are doing in your catch block is re-throwing the exception, there is no need to write the catch block at all"

Answer (score 6):

I wouldn't add 1 & 2 unless I had some specific reason; for example to alter (wrap) the message; there is no need since exceptions will raise upwards anyway. And done incorrectly you can accidentally remove the all-important stack-trace (`throw;` vs `throw ex;` - the first being preferred).

Answer (score 2):

The best answer you can get at [Best Practices for Handling Exceptions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/seyhszts%28v=VS.80%29.aspx)

Answer (score -1):

Here is how **NOT** to handle exceptions.

```
public void method1(){
    try{
        ....
        // all the code goes here
        // declare any helper methods throw throwable
        // eg: private boolean check1() throws Throwable{ ...}
        ....   
    }catch(Throwable t){
       System.out.println("oops...error...good luck debugging. ");
    }
}
```

Comment: No one can suggest a lazier way to handle exceptions that this :)